# How do I modify GRUB to load my HDMI driver before stage 2 is loaded?

Tags: drivers, grub2, hdmi

I dropped my laptop a few weeks ago and broke the screen. The machine itself is still usable I just need to use my TV as a PC monitor. However, the TV currently will not load until after Grub stage 2 is completed. This prevents me from booting from disk, selecting the OS I want to boot into, and all kinds of other fun stuff. Doe's anyone know where I can A) find the name of the exact device driver or module that loads my HDMI port and B) modify the grub.conf file such that I can load the HDMI driver before stage 2? Also, if there is an easier way to do this please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

That would be the Xorg/kernel video drivers, which grub can not use.  It has to rely on the BIOS, so you are stuck.